# Best synonym for "keep" in this context

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

I want to describe a new product which is an improved version of an existing one. The new product has all the features from the existing product, and adds a few new features.

I am looking for a nice way to phrase the above, specifically the verb which is used to say that the new products has all the features from the previous one:

- Product X **keeps** all the features from product Y, and adds ...
- Product X **retains** all the features from product Y, and adds ...
- Product X **maintains** all the features from product Y, and adds ...
- ... other?

Comment: `Retain` is your best bet, imo.

Comment: X has  all the features of Y, PLUS..........

Comment: As Tushar Raj said, with the preposition *of* rather than *from*. "Product X **retains** all the features **of** product Y, and adds ...".

Comment: @Kris is "from" incorrect in this case? Or just a matter of style?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that the problem you have in with your choice of 'keeps' in the first place.

When a product is updated, usually a lot of the features are actually discarded, not kept. This is because at the time they were cutting edge, but now they are old.

As the new product can be considered a descendent of the old product, I would try something like:

> The new product **inherits** all the features of product X that you love, and increases functionality with ...